# Bootstrap dropdown menu not completly visible on mobile device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue on a mobile version of a website where the dropdown menu doesn't appear completely in view because of the position of the particular menu item and the amount of items in the dropdown

[image: Menu Issue]

The image below is how i would like it to appear, so it would focus the area when the parent is clicked.

[image]

Would it be possible to have it so the menu scrolls down to show all the sub items when clicked ?

You can view website at http://www.ndb.ie/2016/. It's using the standard Bootstrap menu code.

Comment: [This is a known bug in bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11243)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override bootstrap style.

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this CSS in your style.css file

For Center Menu in Responsive

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav-justified > .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
        left: 50% !important;
        margin-left: -80px; /* (Half Menu Width in margin left) */
        top: 100%;
    }
}
```

For removing Scroll in Responsive

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible !important;
}
```